# 5 sec delay in yaw rate fusing radar and IMU Robot Localization

Tags: imu, navigation, ros-melodic, robot-localization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using a ground robot and trying to fuse x velocity from the radar and angular z velocity from the IMU in Robot Localization to estimate odometry. I have a consistent 5 sec delay between the angular rate of the IMU vs the angular rate of the odometry message. This obviously make my robot do the turns 5 seconds later than it should.

[Bagfile](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1c4WswB0Srb8kSVbHcioJtZ8GtxdnRHgd/view?usp=sharing)

**IMU message**

```
header: 
  seq: 6420
  stamp: 
    secs: 1583884429
    nsecs:   8326609
  frame_id: "imu_link"
orientation: 
  x: -0.00182108255529
  y: -0.0154610365419
  z: -0.592995859678
  w: 0.805054998377
orientation_covariance: [1e-05, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1e-05, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1e-05]
angular_velocity: 
  x: -0.0146767685242
  y: -0.00264796876277
  z: 0.00796559285187
angular_velocity_covariance: [1.218467815533586e-07, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.218467815533586e-07, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.218467815533586e-07]
linear_acceleration: 
  x: 0.262929823748
  y: 0.0700912966914
  z: 9.64307111704
linear_acceleration_covariance: [8.661248102725949e-06, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 8.661248102725949e-06, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 8.661248102725949e-06]
```

**Radar velocity message**

```
header: 
  seq: 908
  stamp: 
    secs: 1583884414
    nsecs: 817418000
  frame_id: "base_radar_link"
twist: 
  twist: 
    linear: 
      x: 0.955666473669
      y: 0.0772511278807
      z: -0.179226648605
    angular: 
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.0
  covariance: [0.01, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.015, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.05, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
```

**Params**

```
frequency: 30
sensor_timeout: 0.1
two_d_mode: true
transform_time_offset: 0.0
transform_timeout: 0.0
print_diagnostics: true
debug: false
debug_out_file: /path/to/debug/file.txt
publish_tf: true
publish_acceleration: false

map_frame: map              # Defaults to "map" if unspecified
odom_frame: odom            # Defaults to "odom" if unspecified
base_link_frame: base_link  # Defaults to "base_link" if unspecified
world_frame: odom           # Defaults to the value of odom_frame if unspecified

twist0: /mmWaveDataHdl/velocity
twist0_config: [false, false, false,
                false, false, false,
                true,  false, false,
                false, false, false,
                false, false, false]
twist0_queue_size: 3
twist0_nodelay: false

# Jackal's IMU is in ENU frame so it conforms to REP-103
imu0: /imu/data_added_cov
imu0_config: [false, false, false,
              false, false, false,
              false, false, false,
              false,false, true,
              false, false, false]
imu0_nodelay: false
imu0_differential: false
imu0_relative: true
imu0_queue_size: 5
```

My robot cannot move laterally and it is in 2D mode that is why only the x component of the linear velocity is fused in.
Here is a plot in Matlab of a part of the bagfile. You can see how the radar velocity vs odom velocity are both synchronized. However, the angular rate in the odometry is 5 seconds delayed compared to its respective IMU rate (which should be the same since it is the only input for angular rate).
[image: image description]

There is something a bit weird with the covariance. It starts ramping up until 5 seconds and then it goes back down again. The value of the covariance until 5 seconds is low (around 5). But it is still a coincidence that this happens for 5 seconds exactly like the delay.

[image: image description]

I have read several posts of interest and tried different things but none of them worked.

- The IMU `frequency` is 70Hz vs 30Hz of the robot localization. I tried using 70 Hz for the filter and reduce the sensor timeout to avoid queuing messages.
- I have tried to set the `initial_estimate_covariance` for the angular rate z to be 100 as suggested in other posts and I ensured that the `process_noise_covariance` for this angular component is bigger compared to the IMU. It is easy since the covariance of the IMU is really small.

Thanks so much! I appreciate anybody who takes the time to read this :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/351550/5-sec-delay-in-yaw-rate-fusing-radar-and-imu-robot-localization/) by [xaru8145](https://answers.ros.org/users/46622/xaru8145/) on ROS Answers with karma: 105 on 2020-05-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have been on the same situation...its memory leak it's pretty common , set the IMU publisher and EKF freq. to 50 it will sync. never publish any publishers at 70Hz, always go with [10,20,50,80,100,120,150]Hz, these are values worked for me try it out and let me know

---

Originally posted by [Nitesh_j](https://answers.ros.org/users/54485/nitesh_j/) with karma: 65 on 2020-05-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [xaru8145](https://answers.ros.org/users/46622/xaru8145/) on 2020-05-06**:
Thanks for you answer! I have tried what you suggested but did not work.
I have use the topic_tools to set the IMU rate to 50Hz. However, I was not getting more than 42 Hz so I tried with 20 Hz for both the robot_localization and the IMU (did not change anything).

```
  <node name="foo_throttler" type="throttle" pkg="topic_tools" args="messages /imu/data_added_cov 20 /imu/data_low_freq" />
```

**Comment by [Nitesh_j](https://answers.ros.org/users/54485/nitesh_j/) on 2020-05-06**:
How Ur publishing the imu sensor values are using python or c++, which software are using for benchmarking the o/p Freq.

Have u tried rqt to dynamic reconfigure the parameters?

**Comment by [xaru8145](https://answers.ros.org/users/46622/xaru8145/) on 2020-05-06**:
I have the Jackal ground robot from Clearpath that is publishing the `imu/data_raw` Imu topic. I use the [imu_filter_madgwick](http://wiki.ros.org/imu_filter_madgwick) to filter the data to  `imu/data`. This publishes empty covariance values in the orientation so I made a simple cpp code to add a small value to those (code in the next comment). This node publishes `imu/data_added_cov` at 70 Hz and is the one I recorded in the bag file. I am not sure I do not think I can reconfigure parameters since I am replaying from a bagfile.
And to lower the frequency I just run the `topic_tools`  package. But maybe this is not the way I need to write another cpp node using timer or rate.

**Comment by [xaru8145](https://answers.ros.org/users/46622/xaru8145/) on 2020-05-06**:
Code:

```
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include "sensor_msgs/Imu.h"

ros::Publisher imu_pub;
void imuCallback(const sensor_msgs::Imu& msg)
{
  sensor_msgs::Imu imu_msg;
  imu_msg = msg;
  imu_msg.orientation_covariance[0] = 0.00001;
  imu_msg.orientation_covariance[4] = 0.00001;
  imu_msg.orientation_covariance[8] = 0.00001;

  ros::Time imu_time = ros::Time::now();
  imu_msg.header.stamp = imu_time;
  imu_pub.publish(imu_msg);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

ros::init(argc, argv, "imu_add_covariances");
ros::NodeHandle n;
ros::Subscriber imu_sub = n.subscribe("imu/data", 1000, imuCallback);
imu_pub = n.advertise<sensor_msgs::Imu>("imu/data_added_cov", 1000);
ros::spin();

return 0;
}
```